# custom html in drupal subtheme

Tags: drupal

I'm just starting out with drupal and need some custom html for an intricate menu system. My plan is to override the html-generating functions in template.php.

My theme name is "Drupal subtheme" and the navbar I would like to target has the machine name "menu-usm-navbar-small". What should I name the functions that overrides the default html-printouts?

I think I have tried every possible combination of these. Some examples of what I've tried:

```
function drupal_subtheme_menu_link($variables) {
    return "foo";
}

function drupal_subtheme__menu_usm_navbar_small($variables) {
    return "foo";
}
```

Comment: Better to ask at drupal.stackexchange.com. Actually, here are a couple of answers there that should help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/how-to-theme-a-menu-block, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/customizing-menu-link-output. Also, FWIW, your title should be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place custom HTML inside, why do you need to do it trough Drupal's functions?

Let's say, that you want to insert your code into page.tpl.php (most likely) - just open that file, edit it, add your code there.

Since you are overriding some theme - copy that file from original theme, and then edit it (don't forget to clear the cache).